# Cannot copy any larger files to a Google Pixel 4a with Win10 PC, other files work

Tags: windows-10, android, file-transfer

I have connected a Google Pixel 4a (latest updates installed, USB debugging enabled via developer options and USB file transfer enabled in the dropdown menu) to my Win10 PC (also up to date, additionally manually updated MTP drivers for Android hardware) with a USB-C cable that I have used successfully for file transfer before.

The Google Pixel shows up in the Windows explorer window, and the phone's directories can be browsed. It's also possible to copy exisiting files *from* the phone to my PC, **but** not in the other direction, i.e., I cannot copy larger files (more than 10 MB or so) to **any** directory on my phone. Strangely though, smaller files like mp3s (whole folders and single files) as well as jpgs etc. work completely fine. The files in question are not super large (around 500 MB max) and there is more than enough free space on my phone.

When I attempt to copy files (either by Ctrl-C-ing or right-clicking them, then Ctrl-V or right-click > insert), the active Windows file explorer window blinks shortly and the classic "Windows error sound" plays, but nothing else happens.

I also tried deleting all the spaces in the filename, e.g. renaming to testfile.mp4, but that didnt work either.

What makes my Pixel accept certain files and not others? I am truly completely confused by now.

Comment: Has a reboot of PC and smartphone any effect?

Comment: it is not totally clear to me if MTP is file-type agnostic, or if it attempts to affirm if a file is a media file it recognizes. Are the files you have issue with all of one type?

Comment: @Robert both devices have been rebooted.
Yorik: no, it seems to be primarily the file size. A 40 MB .flac file was also not copied when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

After an Android update the file transfer works now flawlessly, although it only works on a USB port directly on the mainboard (not the front USB port I use normally). I do not know which factor was the deciding one.